# Transpose a table with a column containing row headings

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID  Heading     Value
1   Currency:   USD
1   AXA:        6.65
1   ACIS:       1.39
1   Brokerage:  1.7
1   Fee:        0.26
1   Total:      10
2   Currency:   USD
2   AXA:        6.65
2   ACIS:       1.39
2   Brokerage:  1.7
2   Fee:        0.26
2   Total:      10
```

There are in total 350,000 rows of data (not all imported together) which references around 20,000 unique records, which should be shown as below:

```
ID Currency AXA  ACIS Brokerage Fee  Total 
1  USD      6.65 1.39 1.7       0.26 10
2  USD      6.65 1.39 1.7       0.26 10
```

Is there a way using VBA to do this? I'm quite inexperienced with it so I have no idea where to start :/

Comment: have a look at [Transpose a table of data using Excel Formulas](http://chandoo.org/wp/2013/02/01/transpose-table-excel-formula/) for some enlightenment!

Comment: @pnuts currency is actually the same for all records, I just included it for completeness. I'll try a PivotTable now, thanks!

Comment: @pnuts PT did work, and you're right, transpose wasn't the word I wanted, but I couldn't think of a better word to describe closely what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rows with `USD` can be deleted, this may help:

[image: SO25184600 example]